# Boost binary serialization problem with abstract class

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, input, abstract

Ciao folks,

I'm quiet desperate not to find the source of the problem. I'm using Boost:serialization (version 1.46.1) and everything was working fine with `binary_oarchive`. I have a hierarchy of classes and, thus, I use the `register_type()`.

However, where I came to use `binary_iarchive` to unserialize my objects, I got

> error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type

which comes from the call of `register_type()` on the input archive.

After googling I found out that the macro `BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(T)` must be used for the abstract classes. The problem is that it simply doesn't work :). 
Can anyone help me out ?

More about my code :

```
virtual void AbstractClass::initBinarySerialization(binary_iarchive& ia)
        {
            ia.register_type<AbstractClass>();
        }

virtual void SubClass::initBinarySerialization(binary_iarchive& ia)
        {
            AbstractClass::initBinarySerialization(ia);
            ia.register_type<SubClass>();
        }
```

I call `initBinarySerialization` before reading in the archive.

Answer (score 1):

> error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type

It *seems* somewhere in your code, you're creating instance(s) of an *abstract* class. That is why you're getting this error, because creating instance of *abstract* class is forbidden. You can create instance(s) of only *concrete* classes.

You need to tell boost that X is an abstract class, by writing:

```
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(X);
```

Now follow this topic which explains it further:

- [How to serialize derived template classes with Boost.serialize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332602/how-to-serialize-derived-template-classes-with-boost-serialize)

Comment: Thanks @Nawaz, this is true, but it seems that Boost is trying to create this instance.

Comment: As I mentioned, this macro is not working in my case, I use XCode with GCC4.2. However, just in case, I'v put this macro outside the class that I serialize.

Comment: @Shnippoo: How do you think anyone can answer your query without even seeing what you're *actually* doing?