# Boost - class has no member named ‘serialize’ (abstract class)?

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, abstract-class, private-members

I'm trying to serialize my abstract class according to those questions:

- [Get private data members for non intrusive boost serialization C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594917/get-private-data-members-for-non-intrusive-boost-serialization-c)
- [Error serializing an abstract class with boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370727/error-serializing-an-abstract-class-with-boost)
- [Error serializing an abstract class with boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370727/error-serializing-an-abstract-class-with-boost)

My `neuron.h` looks like this:

```
class Neuron {

public:

    struct access;

    API virtual ~Neuron();

    API virtual double activate( double x, double b ) = 0;

};
```

I have to keep all the `Boost` related members in `neuron.cpp` to prevent including Boost headers when using `neuron.h` in some other codes.

My `neuron.cpp` looks like this:

```
#include "Neuron.h"

#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(Neuron);

struct Neuron :: access {
    template <class Archive>
    static void serialize(Archive &ar, Neuron& n, const unsigned int version) {}
};

namespace boost {
    namespace serialization {

        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive & ar, Neuron& n, const unsigned int version)
        {
            Neuron::access::serialize(ar, n, version);
        }

    } // namespace serialization
} // namespace boost

Neuron::~Neuron() {

}
```

The problem is, that when I'm using its inherited classes elsewhere, I'm getting the error

```
***/boost/boost/serialization/access.hpp:116:11: error: ‘class Neuron’ has no member named ‘serialize’
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Well, Neuron::access::serialize(ar, n, version); calls the serialization of neuron which is not implemented. you have to specify exaclty how n is to serialized.

Comment: @Pi So, the `serialize` function is implemented in the `access` struct. I was trying to follow [the example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d76b1aa22076a77) given in the first listed question.

Comment: Yeah, but in the example it says ``ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(a.m_id);` which is concrete way of serializing the member data. You do not have an equivallent

Comment: @Pi Yes, but I have no members to serialize in this abstract class (it's currently just the set of methods) - I'm implementing it only so the inherited classes can call it.

Comment: @Pi Or do you think, that there is some special way to make an empty serialization function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key here is *"when I'm using its inherited classes elsewhere"*. Correct me (and your question, please) if I'm wrong, but this suggests that you are getting the compile error while compiling a source file other than `neuron.cpp`.

This makes sense, given what the compiler has to work with. You might have noticed that changes to one source file tend to not require re-compiling other source files. So adding something -- like an overload of `serialize()` -- to `neuron.cpp` does not change how other translation units are compiled. (It can change how everything is linked together in the end, but we're not there yet.) If another translation unit tries to serialize `Neuron`, the stuff in `neuron.cpp` does not matter. The compiler is not aware of an appropriate overload of `serialize()`, so serializing `Neuron` in another source file results in intrusive serialization. That is, the compiler will look for a member function of `Neuron` called `serialize()`.

**In order for your overload of `serialize()` to affect how other translation units are compiled, it needs to be declared in a header file.**

Since you cannot put Boost stuff in `neuron.h`, you might have to create a new header file, say `neuron_boost.h`. This file would `#include "neuron.h"` then provide the declarations needed for Boost serialization. Source files that serialize descendants of `Neuron` would include `neuron_boost.h` while other source files could continue to include the original `neuron.h`.

Comment: I've managed to get rid of the mentioned error without having to move `serialize` function to another header. The funny thing is, that the same error appeared in a different part of the code. I've tried to describe all the important details in my answer in the `EDIT` section.