# boost::serialization - Serializing a class derived from a generic attribute / feature container

Tags: c++, templates, serialization, boost, containers

I've been struggling the past few weeks to solve an issue I am having with serializing some data using boost::serialization.

I am trying to implement a tabbed editor that utilizes a client/server architecture for a project I am working on. The current design works like this:

- **DerivedTab** extends from a base **Tab** class. (For this example question I have chosen not to include examples of the DerivedTab classes.).
- **Tab** class extends **AttributeContainer** class which contains a map of string attribute names to AttributeBase*.
- **Attribute** is a templated class that extends **AttributeBase**. It is intended to be used as a generic data type that can hold the value any concrete data type.
- And finally, **AttributeBase** derives from **NetworkSerializable** which is a pure abstract base class used as a base object type to identify the contract that objects that can be serialized over a network connection must follow.

All of this is being compiled into a library which is then statically linked into my main application. As you can see, there is quite a bit of indirection going on and quite a few pitfalls that I'm trying to work around with serializing with boost::serialization. I've stripped out all additional code not pertinent to getting these classes to serialize. However, the example code is still quite lengthy.

main.cpp:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include "Tab.h"

using namespace test;

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    std::ostringstream oarchiveStream;

    boost::archive::text_oarchive outputArchive(oarchiveStream);

    Tab* tab = new Tab("temp");

    bool tempBool = true;
    tab->RegisterAttribute("tempBool", "a temp boolean", &tempBool);

    std::string tempString("1234");
    tab->RegisterAttribute("tempString", "a temp string", &tempString);

    outputArchive << tab;
}
```

Tab.h:

```
#ifndef __TAB_H__
#define __TAB_H__

#include "AttributeContainer.h"

#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp> 

namespace test
{

class Tab : public AttributeContainer
{
friend class boost::serialization::access;
public:

    Tab(const std::string tabName);
    virtual ~Tab();

protected:
    Tab();

    template<class archive>
    inline void serialize_attributes(archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(AttributeContainer);
        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("TabName", _tabName);
    }

    virtual void serialize(boost::archive::text_oarchive& oa, const unsigned int version);
    virtual void serialize(boost::archive::text_iarchive& ia, const unsigned int version);

private:
    std::string _tabName;

};

} // namespace test

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(test::Tab);

#endif // #ifndef __TAB_H__
```

Tab.cpp:

```
#include "Tab.h"

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(test::Tab);

using namespace test;

Tab::Tab(const std::string tabName) : _tabName(tabName)
{
}

Tab::~Tab()
{
}

Tab::Tab() : _tabName("")
{
}

void Tab::serialize(boost::archive::text_oarchive& oa, const unsigned int version)
{
    std::cout << "Tab::serialize" << std::endl;
    serialize_attributes(oa, version);
}
void Tab::serialize(boost::archive::text_iarchive& ia, const unsigned int version)
{
    serialize_attributes(ia, version);
}
```

AttributeContainer.h:

```
#ifndef __ATTRIBUTE_CONTAINER_H__
#define __ATTRIBUTE_CONTAINER_H__

#include "NetworkSerializable.h"

#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include "Attribute.h"

namespace test
{

class AttributeContainer : public NetworkSerializable
{
friend class boost::serialization::access;
public:
    std::map<std::string, AttributeBase*> _attributes;

    AttributeContainer() {};
    virtual ~AttributeContainer() {};

    template <typename _T>
    void RegisterAttribute(const std::string& name, const std::string& description, _T* var)
    {
        std::map<std::string, AttributeBase*>::const_iterator pos;

        if ( (pos = _attributes.find(name)) == _attributes.end() )
        {
            Attribute<_T>* attribute = new Attribute<_T>(name, description, var);

            _attributes.insert(std::map<std::string, AttributeBase*>::value_type(name, attribute));
        }
    };

    template <class archive>
    inline void serialize_attributes(archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & _attributes;
    };

    virtual void serialize(boost::archive::text_oarchive& oa, const unsigned int version);
    virtual void serialize(boost::archive::text_iarchive& ia, const unsigned int version);

}; // end class AtributeContainer

} // end namespace test

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(test::AttributeContainer);

#endif // #ifndef __ATTRIBUTE_CONTAINER_H__
```

AttributeContainer.cpp:

```
#include "AttributeContainer.h"

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(test::AttributeContainer);

using namespace test;

void AttributeContainer::serialize(boost::archive::text_oarchive& oa, const unsigned int version)
{
    std::cout << "AttributeContainer::serialize" << std::endl;
    serialize_attributes(oa, version);
}

void AttributeContainer::serialize(boost::archive::text_iarchive& ia, const unsigned int version)
{
    serialize_attributes(ia, version);
}
```

Attribute.h:

```
#ifndef __ATTRIBUTE_H__
#define __ATTRIBUTE_H__

#include "AttributeBase.h"

namespace test
{

template <typename _T>
class Attribute : public AttributeBase
{
friend class AttributeContainer;
friend class boost::serialization::access;
public: 
    typedef _T AttributeType;

    Attribute() : _data(0) {}
    Attribute(const std::string& name, const std::string& description, AttributeType* var) : _data(var)
    {
        _name = name;
        _description = description;
    }

    virtual ~Attribute() {}

protected:
    AttributeType* _data;

    template <class archive>
    inline void serialize_base(archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(AttributeBase);
        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("Value", *_data);
    }

    virtual void serialize(boost::archive::text_oarchive& oa, const unsigned int version)
    {
        std::cout << "Attribute::serialize" << std::endl;
        serialize_base(oa, version);
    }

    virtual void serialize(boost::archive::text_iarchive& ia, const unsigned int version)
    {
        serialize_base(ia, version);
    }
};

} // namespace test

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(test::Attribute<bool>);
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(test::Attribute<std::string>);

#endif // #ifndef __ATRIBUTE_H__
```

Attribute.cpp:

```
#include "Attribute.h"

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(test::Attribute<bool>);
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(test::Attribute<std::string>);

using namespace test;
```

AttributeBase.h:

```
#ifndef __ATTRIBUTE_BASE_H__
#define __ATTRIBUTE_BASE_H__

#include "NetworkSerializable.h"

#include <string>

namespace test
{

class AttributeBase : public NetworkSerializable
{
friend class AttributeContainer;
friend class boost::serialization::access;
public:
    AttributeBase();
    virtual ~AttributeBase();

protected:
    AttributeBase& operator=(const AttributeBase&);
    AttributeBase(const AttributeBase&);

protected:
    std::string _name;
    std::string _description;

    template<class archive>
    inline void serialize_attributes(archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("Name", _name);
        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("Description", _description);
    }

    virtual void serialize(boost::archive::text_oarchive& oa, const unsigned int version);
    virtual void serialize(boost::archive::text_iarchive& ia, const unsigned int version);

}; // end class AttributeBase

} // end namespace test

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(test::AttributeBase);
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(test::AttributeBase);

#endif // #ifndef __ATTRIBUTE_BASE_H__
```

NetworkSerializable.h:

```
#ifndef __NETWORK_SERIALIZABLE_H__
#define __NETWORK_SERIALIZABLE_H__
#pragma warning(disable:4244)

#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

namespace test
{

class NetworkSerializable
{
friend class boost::serialization::access;
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<NetworkSerializable> NetworkSerializablePtr;

    NetworkSerializable() {};

protected:
    virtual void serialize(boost::archive::text_oarchive& oa, const unsigned int version) = 0;
    virtual void serialize(boost::archive::text_iarchive& ia, const unsigned int version) = 0;

};

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(NetworkSerializable);

} // namespace test

#endif // #ifndef __NETWORK_SERIALIZABLE_H__
```

I've tried to make the code as concise and minimal as possible to fully demonstrate the issue I am having.

The output from the provided code is:

```
Tab::serialize  
Tab::serialize
```

When the output should be:

```
Tab::serialize  
AttributeContainer::serialize  
Attribute::serialize  
AttributeBase::serialize  
Attribute::serialize  
AttributeBase::serialize
```

There is quite a bit of code here for someone to digest so I would be very thankful if anyone can  offer any insight where I might have strayed along the boost serialization path.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to serialize derived template classes with Boost.serialize?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332602/how-to-serialize-derived-template-classes-with-boost-serialize)

Comment: Please, next time, keep your example to the point. In reducing to a SSCCE you not only risk spotting (the) problem(s) yourself, but also you don't require random strangers to cope with walls of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell: your `serialize` member functions should **not** be virtual.   Making them virtual results in the call to `static_cast<AttributeContainer*>(this)->serialize(...)`, made by `boost::serialization::base_object` inside of `Tab::serialize_attributes`, landing back in `Tab::serialize` through virtual function dispatch.

Here's a working single-file example based on your code:

```
namespace serial_test
{
    using namespace std;

    class NetworkSerializable {
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
    public:
        typedef std::shared_ptr<NetworkSerializable> NetworkSerializablePtr;

        NetworkSerializable() {};

    protected:
//    void serialize(boost::archive::text_oarchive& oa, const unsigned int version) = 0;
//    void serialize(boost::archive::text_iarchive& ia, const unsigned int version) = 0;
    };

    BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(NetworkSerializable);



    class AttributeBase : public NetworkSerializable {
        friend class AttributeContainer;
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
    public:
        AttributeBase() {}
        virtual ~AttributeBase() {}

    protected:
        std::string _name;
        std::string _description;

    template<class archive>
        inline void serialize_attributes(archive& ar, const unsigned int version) {
            ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("Name", _name);
            ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("Description", _description);
        }

            void serialize(boost::archive::text_oarchive& oa, const unsigned int version) {
        cout << "AttributeBase::serialize" << endl;
        serialize_attributes(oa, version);
            }
            void serialize(boost::archive::text_iarchive& ia, const unsigned int version) {
        serialize_attributes(ia, version);
            }

    }; // end class AttributeBase


    template <typename _T>
    class Attribute : public AttributeBase {
        friend class AttributeContainer;
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
    public:
        typedef _T AttributeType;

        Attribute() : _data(0) {}
        Attribute(const std::string& name, const std::string& description, AttributeType* var) : _data(var) {
            _name = name;
            _description = description;
        }

        virtual ~Attribute() {}

    protected:
        AttributeType* _data;

        template <class archive>
        void serialize_base(archive& ar, const unsigned int version) {
            ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(AttributeBase);
            ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("Value", *_data);
        }

        void serialize(boost::archive::text_oarchive& oa, const unsigned int version) {
            std::cout << "Attribute::serialize" << std::endl;
            serialize_base(oa, version);
        }

        void serialize(boost::archive::text_iarchive& ia, const unsigned int version) {
            serialize_base(ia, version);
        }
    };






    class AttributeContainer : public NetworkSerializable {
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
    public:
        std::map<std::string, AttributeBase*> _attributes;

        AttributeContainer() {};
        virtual ~AttributeContainer() {};

        template <typename _T>
        void RegisterAttribute(const std::string& name, const std::string& description, _T* var) {
            std::map<std::string, AttributeBase*>::const_iterator pos;

            if ( (pos = _attributes.find(name)) == _attributes.end() ) {
                Attribute<_T>* attribute = new Attribute<_T>(name, description, var);

                _attributes.insert(std::map<std::string, AttributeBase*>::value_type(name, attribute));
            }
        };

        template <class archive>
        void serialize_attributes(archive& ar, const unsigned int version) {
            ar & _attributes;
        };

              void serialize(boost::archive::text_oarchive& oa, const unsigned int version) {
                    std::cout << "AttributeContainer::serialize" << std::endl;
                    serialize_attributes(oa, version);
              }
              void serialize(boost::archive::text_iarchive& ia, const unsigned int version) {
                    serialize_attributes(ia, version);
        }

    }; // end class AtributeContainer





    class Tab : public AttributeContainer {
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
    public:
        Tab(const std::string tabName)
            : _tabName(tabName) {}
            virtual ~Tab() {}

    protected:
        Tab()
              : _tabName("") {}

        template<class archive>
        inline void serialize_attributes(archive& ar, const unsigned int version) {
//            ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_BASE_OBJECT_NVP(AttributeContainer);
            ar & boost::serialization::base_object<AttributeContainer>(*this);
            ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("TabName", _tabName);
        }

            void serialize(boost::archive::text_oarchive& oa, const unsigned int version) {
                std::cout << "Tab::serialize" << std::endl;
                serialize_attributes(oa, version);
            }

      void serialize(boost::archive::text_iarchive& ia, const unsigned int version) {
                serialize_attributes(ia, version);
            }

    private:
    std::string _tabName;

    };



    void test() {
        std::ostringstream oarchiveStream;

        boost::archive::text_oarchive outputArchive(oarchiveStream);

        Tab* tab = new Tab("temp");

        bool tempBool = true;
        tab->RegisterAttribute("tempBool", "a temp boolean", &tempBool);
        std::string tempString("1234");
        tab->RegisterAttribute("tempString", "a temp string", &tempString);

            outputArchive << tab;
    }

} // namespace serial_test



BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(serial_test::AttributeBase);
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(serial_test::AttributeBase);

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(serial_test::Attribute<bool>);
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(serial_test::Attribute<string>);
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(serial_test::Attribute<bool>);
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(serial_test::Attribute<string>);

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_KEY(serial_test::Tab);
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_IMPLEMENT(serial_test::Tab);
```

Comment: That's exactly what the problem was. I think I was too caught up in ensuring I had the proper macros to describe the proper scenario and didn't even think that my strategy of having a pure abstract base class ensure that derived classes of NetworkSerializable define ::serialize() would be the issue. Many thanks for pointing this out!!! **Moral of the story is when using boost::serialization, ::serialize methods should not be made virtual.**

I had referenced the post marked as duplicate above and attempted its implementation as a guide. Obviously I overlooked something. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad your problem is solved. Please consider accepting the answer ;)