# C++: serialize/de-serialize classes as follow:

Tags: c++, class, templates, serialization, boost

```
template<typename T>
class MultidimArray:
{
public:
    T* data;
    long int xinit;
    ...
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version){
            ar & data;
            ar & xinit;
            ar & ...;
    }
};


stringstream ss; 
void serializateWs(){
    MultidimArray<DOUBLE> Mpack;
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ss);
    oa << Mpack;
}
```

Compile error: request for member ‘serialize’ in ‘t’, which is of non-class type ‘double’.
But it will be fine without "T * data". I found an answer [How to serialize derived template classes with Boost.serialize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332602/how-to-serialize-derived-template-classes-with-boost-serialize)
I add this line "oa.template register_type< MultidimArray >();".
But I got this " error| ‘template’ (as a disambiguator) is only allowed within templates" when compiling.
How can I serialize and deserialize this kind of class?

Comment: What is T in your case? If `T` is another class, did you implement `serialize` for it?

Comment: @farcost T can be any class, but I set it to double here

Answer (score 0):

Use the array wrapper: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/serialization/doc/wrappers.html#arrays, e.g. like:

```
ar & boost::serialization::make_array(data, xinit)
   & ...;
```

Registering types has nothing to with things, unless T is a polymorphic pointer.

Comment: It's done, Thanks a lot,.but I used another way instead of serializing a object.